# Lumen - How to create a request object that can be accessed by app('request') from a different file?

Tags: php, request, lumen

My lumen application has a common trait that records every add/update/delete activity of every table in the database.  This trait is used in a basemodel which is then extended for all applicable table model files like below.

```
namespace App\Models;
class BaseModel extends Model {
   use RecordsActivity; //this is the common trait
}

namespace App\Models;
class User extends BaseModel {}
```

Till date, my application only had APIs which will be consumed by the Angular client.  So, every API endpoint comes with a request in which I'll store a property in the middleware as end_point_id (dynamic for every API call).  This end_point_id will be stored as part of recording add/update/delete transaction to relate the transactions with the endpoint transaction like below.

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
class APIMiddleware {
   //check and do some process
   $request->merge(['end_point_id' => $end_point_id]);
}

namespace App\Http\Traits;
trait RecordsActivity {
   //other preparation statements
   AuditTrail::create([
      "end_point_id" => app('request')->end_point_id,
      'table_name' => $model->getTable(),
      'object_id' => $model->id,
      'field_name' => $field_name,
      'old_value' => $old_value,
      'new_value' => $new_value,
      'event_timestamp' => $model->updated_at]);
}
```

By referring app('request'), the trait was getting the value of end_point_id when consuming as an API.  Now I'm writing a job to perform some batch process on a few tables commonly used by API.  Now I've renamed end_point_id as 'event_id' and added a new column as 'event_trigger' to hold 'API/JOB'.  When a job is executed, the table add/update/delete transactions will be saved in audit_trails table with event_trigger as 'JOB' and event_id as an integer job_id.

Since the job does not have an input request, I tried creating an Illuminate\Http\Request object and included a property named 'event_id' using $request->replace (also tried merge method).  By doing so, the newly included property is not accessible when tried as app('request')->event_id.  Below is the printed log info.

```
TestJob.php 
namespace App\Console\Commands;
class TestJob extends Command {

   public function handle() {
     $request = new \Illuminate\Http\Request;
     $request->replace(['event_id' => 11]);
     Log::info(print_r($request->all(), true));
     //prints output as Array
     //(
     //     [event_id] => 11
     //)
     Log::info(print_r(app('request')->all(),true));
     //prints output as Array
     //(
     //)
    }
}
```

Because `app('request')->all()` prints empty array, during any table update, the trait fails as the value of event_id is not present.

I tried creating `$request = new \Request()`, it failed as

> "call to undefined method replace()";

same for `merge()` too.  Same error when trying to create a Guzzle request.

Since lumen is stateless, passing a value from one component to another through request object was the only option that came to my mind.  Any help to resolve the issue is appreciated.  I would like to know how to create a request object from a job that will be accessible using app('request') command from another file.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Why would you merge it in a scenario where there is no `Request` context? I understand why you try to do this, but in this scenario it does not make much sense, so I would recommend using an alternative approach.

What I would recommend is storing a private static variable in `RecordsActivity` with a public static getter and setter method. This way you can set this variable from either the middleware or the command and refer internally to this variable (when you create `AuditTrail`). By doing this you have a clear separation and no mixin of http elements when there is no http context. By doing this you make the `AuditTrail` independent of the context (http or command) which makes your code a lot better and modular.

I hope this helps you, if you have any questions feel free to ask.

Comment: I tried using accessor and mutator to add custom attribute in baseModel to pass event_id field. But in order to get the value of event_id in my trait, I need to pass the event_id in every INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE transaction by passing value to that property.  
`
`$data = new \App\Models\Table1.php
$data->event_id = $event_id;
$data->col1 = $col1;
$data->save();
`

Can't this be achieved by setting the event_id at one place (mostly in middleware) which will be fetched from each of the model's custom attribute in trait?  How to do so?

Comment: You mean that when you call $data->save() it will automatically get and assign the correct event_id variable based on the static variable?

Comment: yes more like that.  For that to happen, the event_id should have been saved somewhere for the model to pickup.  Since Lumen is stateless, I couldn't find a way of how to accomplish this.  In my existing application, as I explained in my question, request object carried that event_id value from middleware to trait.  But where and how to pass the event_id so that it will be received as an additional custom attribute for every applicable model in the audit trail process performed in trait.

Comment: You can use the static setter in the model to set it in the handle method of your command, since it is static it will also be statically available in your model class (but only for that request). You are correct that lumen is stateless but it will persist those static variables for either one request or for one command. So you can access it statically in your model if you set it in the command